# Using ':' (colon) operator instead of '=' equals to throws error

Tags: javascript, constructor

Here is a sample constructor function that throws `"SyntaxError: missing ; before statement   Line 3"`

```
function party() {
    this.cakes = "Truffle Cake",
    this.cookies = "Good Day",
    this.drinks: "Wine";
    }
```

While this does not

```
function party() {
    this.cakes = "Truffle Cake",
    this.cookies = "Good Day",
    this.drinks = "Wine";
    }
```

the difference from first in the second being the use of equals to (=) operator instead of (:) colon operator to assign value `drinks` property a value. I would like to know the logic why Javascript throws error in the first case.

Also why in the following party.cake etc alerts with "Undefined" as party is an object in itself

```
function party() {
    cake = "Truffle Cake";
    cookies = "Good Day";
    drinks = "Wine";
    }

    alert("Cakes in Tonight's Party: " + party.cake);
    alert("Cookies in Tonight's Party: " + party.cookies);
    alert("Drinks in Tonight's Party: " + party.drinks);
```

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read [MDN Working with objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) - it covers the basics briefly, but I think that should be enough to show you where you went wrong

Comment: The logic is that language by nature has syntax, and the first one is invalid syntax. Why *should* it work?

Comment: As to the last code block, again why *shouldn't* it give you `undefined`? Have you read any JavaScript tutorial that tells you that doing assignments inside a function will add properties to that function?

Comment: Yes I have though, I still in initial stages. Moreover function fundamentally are JS objects so if I do `drinks: "Wine";` (removing `this` operator) in the first example, syntax error does not appear. How would you explain that?

Comment: Please don't ask two questions in a single post. One question per post makes questions more useful to others.

Answer (score 1):

The colon is used to separate a property from the value in an object literal.  The equals separates the property/variable from a value that is being set.

The error message is correct,  you need an equals because you are setting a property. It is not an object literal.

Comment: 1st is a constructor function and constructor is an object that implements the internal [[call]] and [[construct]] methods. Moreover if I do `drinks: "Wine";` (removing `this` operator) in the first example, syntax error does not appear. How would you explain that?

Comment: That's because in that case, `drink:` is considered a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label). I don't understand what you are trying to get at with your first statement, it was pretty clear that it is a constructor